# zooming proportionally to fit inside the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming

[image]

I've a `#fixed-div` and a `#resize-div` and the dimension is as follows:

**#fixed-div**

```
=> width :: 550px;
=> height:: 450px;
```

and the **#resize-div** is dynamic.

Now, I want to apply the zoom css for `#resize-div` to be inside the `#fixed-div` like in the above picture.

I'm trying to calculate the zoom value for the `#resize-div` suppose if I've the following dimension for `#resize-div`:

```
=> width :: 650px;
=> height:: 1100px;
```

So, How would you calculate the ratio here. (it took me about 3 days but still couldn't understand how should I do?)

Please help me on this kindly.

Comment: a fiddle link will help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ratioX = biggerX / smallerX;
var ratioY = biggerY / smallerY;

if (ratioX > ratioY) {
    var zoom = ratioX;
} else {
    var zoom = ratioY;
}
```

and then you set that zoom property to the element:

```
$('.inner').css({
    'transform': 'scale('+zoom+','+zoom+')' //remember to use vendor prefixes
});
```

You'll need to set `transform-origin: 0% 0%;` on the inner one

Comment: Will this proportionally zoom? I think x, y you are setting would stretch the resizing div. But I need proportionally....

Comment: it helped me (I changed > to < and worked in my case)

Comment: That was the only part where I was unsure. I thought I have a 50% chance and if it's wrong he'll figure it out. And you did :)